# NaN в boost::accumulators

Tags: c++, boost

При вычислении `boost::accumulators::mean(acc)` в некоторых случаях появляется NaN. Хочу понять, при каких условиях такое получается. Как вывести на экран все элементы из `boost::accumulators` или проверить, есть ли там элементы?

Comment: Думаю, NaN появляется если в данных присутствует NaN. Ну и наверняка всякие невозможные штуки, наподобие среднего арифметического пустого набора, тоже дают NaN.

Comment: Одно из решений:
boost::accumulators::count(acc) == 0
или
std::isnan(boost::accumulators::mean(acc)